# Nome repetido de medalhas: Convenção

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Temos duas medalhas com o nome `Convenção`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seus nomes e descrições em inglês são:

### Caucus

> Visited an election during any phase of an active election and had enough reputation to cast a vote

e

### Convention

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta

Acredito que isso tenha sido um equívoco na hora de traduzir e passou despercebido até agora, sendo assim penso que isso deve ser mudado.

`caucus` de acordo com o Google Tradutor significa `convenção política`, a propósito, nunca ouvido falar dessa palavra antes.

Acredito que poderíamos manter o nome da medalha para o caso dos 10 posts com pontuação de 2 no meta e mudar o nome da outra. Entretanto, não tenho uma sugestão.

Alguém?

Comment: Também tem duas chamadas "revisor" (copy editor e proofreader)

Comment: @bfavaretto bem observado, não tinha visto. Só para entender melhor, você deu esse exemplo pra mostrar que é _normal_ termos duas medalhas com o mesmo nome ou está apenas apontando outro caso similar?

Comment: Estou apontando outro caso similar, não tem nada de normal!

Comment: @bfavaretto acho melhor criar outra pergunta para não misturar os assuntos, se ninguém criar em alguns dias eu crio

Comment: Ok, eu estou numa correria danada, quem sabe durante o carnaval consigo tirar o atraso de postagens no meta.

Comment: @bfavaretto não se esqueça da [sua própria opinião](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/quem-e-strunk-white-em-portugues/474#474) ao pensar sobre a medalha com nome repetido Revisor. São muitas as possibilidades :)

Comment: @bfavaretto você consegue consertar os nomes das medalhas? E as descrições?

Comment: Não posso :( Mas aos poucos vou varrer tudo que falta e passar pro Gabe.

Comment: Corrigido com a sugestão do Math

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisei um pouco sobre o que seria uma convenção política, e achei [esse texto aqui](http://pessoas.hsw.uol.com.br/convencoes-politicas1.htm).

O texto todo é muito extenso, quem quiser leia no link, mas eu achei as seguintes passagens algo a ser relevado:

> A convenção política é uma tradição americana focada nos partidos políticos que definem as escolhas ao governo há quase dois séculos.

;

> Originalmente, o principal propósito das convenções políticas era nomear o candidato do partido à presidência.

e

> Hoje, as primárias presidenciais tornaram as convenções desnecessárias para propósitos práticos.

Citei tudo isso para concluir uma coisa: **Caucus não é um bom nome para medalha :)**

Pelo mesmo motivo citado no comentário do @bfavaretto com relação à sugestão Primárias:

> A ideia é boa, mas tem um problema. A eleição é dividida em 3 fases: "indicação", "primárias" e "eleição". E a medalha de bronze (caucus) você ganha por visitar a página da eleição a qualquer momento, então pode ficar confuso.

Você ganha a medalha Caucus por visitar a eleição a qualquer momento, mas Caucus é apenas a parte da nomeação, portanto, errônea. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Considerando que estou certo, não devemos nos apegar ao nome original (Caucus, em inglês) para dar o nome da nossa medalha.

## Eleitor

Sendo assim, sugiro **Eleitor**, pois você visitou o site em período de eleição e tem o direito de votar.

A diferença das eleições do SO para as eleições políticas no Brasil é que aqui no SO você não é obrigado a votar, mas acho que não deveríamos nos apegar a isso.

---

<sup>Podemos chamar a medalha de "Eleitor de 16 anos de idade", pois não é obrigatório =P < /joke></sup>

Comment: Gosto de "eleitor", mesmo coincidindo com o nome da última fase do processo eleitoral. Mas "eleitor" também poderia ser o nome da medalha Electorate. Vou pensar mais sobre o assunto e ver se tenho alguma outra sugestão.

Comment: @bfavaretto o Electorate foi traduzido como Eleitorado, mas eu nunca tinha parado para pensar no pq do nome Eleitorado, vale a pena a reflexão

Comment: Pois é, "Eleitorado" não é esquisito também?

Comment: @bfavaretto é esquisito sim. Inclusive a própria Electorate, assim como Caucus pode ser que ela não faça tanto sentido assim. Tenho que pesquisar um pouco, mas não hoje, depois eu volto e digo o que conclui

Comment: +1 concordo plenamente com o Eleitor.

Comment: Também concordo com Eleitor. Sobre a medalha "Eleitorado", talvez a tradução também esteja correta. _Electorate_ significa literalmente _eleitorado_, e acredito que traduza o sentido da medalha (votar em 600 questões...), i.e., quem recebe é porque faz parte do eleitorado.

Comment: @bfavaretto 4 votos já é suficiente para ser declarada uma vitória? Já dá pra atualizar o nome dessa também? :)

Comment: Aí já não sei. O Gabe está mexendo no que ele tem certeza.

Answer (score 1):

Uma tradução livre para *Caucus*, que seria uma descrição mais brasileira da etapa do processo de eleições ligado a essa medalha:

#### Peneira

Não sei se em Portugal existe essa gíria, mas aqui no Brasil "peneira" é uma seleção preliminar na qual o número inicial de candidatos (propostas, jogadores de futebol, ou seja lá o que estiver sendo selecionado) é drasticamente reduzido.

Comment: Peneira para filtrar alguma coisa, isso?

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, tipo peneira de futebol, conhece essa?

Comment: @Math Não conheço, aqui só se usa peneira quando se fala em "peneirar farinha" e é um **objeto**: http://www.dueceira.pt/trilhos/imgs/peneira_lousa.jpg

Comment: -1 porque não se encaixa no pt_PT

Comment: @JorgeB. obrigado pela explicação. PS: aqui tb usamos peneira para peneirar farinha, nata, areia e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Ah só a titulo de curiosidade também se usa peneira, no caso "peneiras", para uma pessoa que seja muito vaidosa: " Demonstração de vaidade ou presunção"

Comment: @JorgeB. essa é nova para mim, rsrs

Comment: Peneira? Acho que Filtro ficaria melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Eu chamaria a medalha de bronze de **"Primárias"**.

Manteria a medalha de prata *"Convenção"*.

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas tem um problema. A eleição é dividida em 3 fases: "indicação", "primárias" e "eleição". E a medalha de bronze (caucus) você ganha por visitar a página da eleição a qualquer momento, então pode ficar confuso.

Comment: @bfavaretto acabei de pensar em uma coisa estranha: "A **eleição** é dividida em indicação, primárias e **eleição**", tá certo isso? Pois se a última fase também for _eleição_ minha resposta pode não fazer sentido

Comment: Exatamente, mas eu concordo com você que Caucus não é um bom nome pra medalha.

Comment: -1 Não acho que primárias de adeque a descrição da medalha.