# Por que temos no Meta medalhas relacionadas a recompensas?

Tags: suporte, meta, recompensa

Por que temos as medalhas Altruísta, Benfeitor, Investidor e Promotor na [lista de medalhas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) do Meta? Todas elas são relacionadas a recompensas, e até onde sei não podemos oferecer recompensas no Meta (ou podemos?).

Não temos por exemplo as medalhas Convenção, Constituinte, Quórum e Convenção (sim, [convenção duas vezes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/914/3117)), logo a lista de medalhas no Meta e no Principal já são diferentes por conta disso. Existe algum motivo em especial que não tiraram as medalhas relacionadas a recompensas?

Comment: Isso deve ser um resquício do MSE, onde a reputação é mostrada e pode-se sim oferecer recompensas. Nos metas dos sites individuais, não faz mesmo sentido ter essas medalhas.